# Solve for $P$ in $M=P\cdot C$ with $C=diagflat(P^{-1}\cdot W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve for $P$ in the following equation:

$$M=P\cdot C$$

with

$$C=diagflat(P^{-1}\cdot W)$$

where $P$ is the unknown $3\times 3$ colourspace primaries matrix, $M$ is a known $3\times 3$ normalised primary matrix converting from RGB to CIE XYZ tristimulus values and $W$ is a known $3\times 1$ matrix for the whitepoint tristimulus values.

$diagflat$ is a function converting the given $3\times 1$ matrix to the $3\times 3$ diagonal matrix such as:

$$diagflat([1, 2, 3])=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

Computing $M$ in $$M=P\cdot C$$ where

$$P=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
7.34700000e-01 &  0.00000000e+00 &  1.00000000e-04 \\
2.65300000e-01 &  1.00000000e+00 & -7.70000000e-02 \\
0.00000000e+00 &  0.00000000e+00 &  1.07690000e+00 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

and

$$W=\left[\begin{array}{c}
0.95264607 \\
1. \\
1.00882518 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

yields:

$$M=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
9.52552396e-01 & 0.00000000e+00 &  9.36786317e-05 \\
3.43966450e-01 & 7.28166097e-01 & -7.21325464e-02 \\
0.00000000e+00 & 0.00000000e+00 &  1.00882518e+00 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

The practical case in solving for $P$ is finding the primaries of a given RGB colourspace model when the whitepoint tristimulus values and the RGB to CIE XYZ matrix are known. Usually one has a set of primaries and whitepoint tristimulus values and computes the RGB to XYZ matrix.

[1]. SMPTE. (1993). Derivation of Basic Television Color Equations. In RP 177:1993 (Vol. RP 177:199, pp. 1–4). doi:10.5594/S9781614821915

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with some of your terminology, e.g., "colourspace primaries matrix" and $M$ being "normalized". So I'll just solve the more general purely linear algebraic problem. I'll assume everything in sight is non-singular.

You wish to solve
$$
(*)\ \ \ \ \ M = P\ \ \text{diagflat}(P^{-1} W).
$$
for $P$ where $M$ and $W$ are known. Let
$$
(**)\ \ \ \ \ A = \text{diagflat} (P^{-1} W).
$$
Then $A$ is a $3\times 3$ diagonal matrix. Let $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$ be the diagonal entries of $A$.

Observe $(*)$ can be rearranged as
$$
P^{-1} = A M^{-1}
$$
and therefore
$$
P^{-1} W = A M^{-1} W.
$$
Recalling the definition of $A$ in $(**)$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
A &=& \text{diagflat}(P^{-1} W) \\
 &=& \text{diagflat} (A M^{-1} W).
\end{eqnarray}
But this means
$$
A_i = A_i (M^{-1} W)_i
$$
for $i=1,2,3$ where $(M^{-1} W)_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ member of $M^{-1} W$. That means you'd better have
$$
M^{-1} W = \mathbf{1}
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the $3\times 1$ matrix of $1$'s. This is equivalent to $W = M\mathbf{1}$, i.e., the sum of the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of $M$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ member of $W$ for all $i$. (I see this is true in your example, so I assume your problem domain somehow imposes the constraint $W = M\mathbf{1}$.)

Assuming $W = M\mathbf{1}$, there are infinitely many solutions $P$ for your problem. Just take
$$
P = M A^{-1}
$$
for any non-singular diagonal matrix $A$. I assume you need $P$ to conform to some additional problem-specific constraint. Choose $A$ accordingly.

Comment: I need to spend some time with your answer Will but we found a way to compute the primaries as follows:

$(M.I)^T$ where M is the 3×3 normalised primary matrix, I is a 3x3 identity matrix. We basically take the transpose of the dot between M and I.